Connection reset (SocketException) during image upload to Amazon AWS S3 using OkHttp on Android with certain operator
I'm encountering a java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error while attempting to upload an image to an Amazon AWS S3 pre-signed URL using Android Upload Service with OkHttp with Zain network operator.
Issue Description:
The upload fails during the SSL handshake. This issue is specific to certain network conditions:

Occurs when using Zain (a network operator in the Middle East).
Upload works fine when switching to STC (another network operator) or when turning off the VPN.

The error does not seem to occur with other servers, only with Amazon AWS S3.
Steps to Reproduce:

Set up an image upload request to a pre-signed URL on Amazon AWS S3 using OkHttp and Android Upload Service.
Use a device connected via Zain network operator with VPN enabled.
Attempt the upload, and observe the Connection reset error.
Repeat with STC as the operator and VPN disabled, and observe the upload working successfully.

Expected Behavior:
The upload should complete successfully over HTTPS regardless of network operator or VPN.

OS and Library Versions:

Android Upload Service Version: 4.9.2
Android Version and API Level: Android 14 (API Level 34)
HTTP Stack: OkHttpStack


Code Sample:
suspend fun uploadPhoto(
    uploadId: String,
    preSignedUrl: String,
    mimeType: String,
    filePath: String,
    postName: String,
) {
    val request = BinaryUploadRequest(context, preSignedUrl).apply {
        setUploadID(uploadId)
        setMethod("PUT")
        addHeader("Content-Type", mimeType)
        setFileToUpload(filePath)
        startUpload()
    }
}


Debug Log:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:191)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:238)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at net.gotev.uploadservice.okhttp.OkHttpStackRequest.getResponse(OkHttpStackRequest.kt:94)
    at net.gotev.uploadservice.HttpUploadTask.upload(HttpUploadTask.kt:50)
    at net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.kt:144)


Troubleshooting Attempts:

Switching from Zain to STC resolves the issue, suggesting it might be network-specific.
Disabling VPN also allows the upload to succeed.
Tested the upload process with different HTTP stacks; issue persists with OkHttpStack.


